# How to change "constant" value on request in java bean on the fly (hibernate)?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I'm using Hibernate 5.0.3 and tomcat8 server.

In first part(object) of returning Json response with rest i have data about error message, httpcode, api version and app version. It's called MessageJson, second part is object/returning value that user requested.

How to implement or change values of appVersion atribute on the fly without restarting server and uploading new .war to it? Atribute is marked in code below:

```
public class MessageJson {

    private int httpCode;
    private String errorMessage;
    private String apiVer;
    private String appVersion ;

    public MessageJson (int httpCode, String errorMessage) {
        this.httpCode = httpCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.apiVer = "0.905";
        this.appVersion = "1.350";//How to change this value without restarting server? And without reading from DB on every single request from api?

    }
}
```

Here is structure of complete object/Json that is returned from Api:

```
public class ResponseJson {

    private MessageJson message;
    private Object body;

    public ResponseJson (MessageJson message, Object body) {
        this.body = body;
        this.message = message;
    }
```

Does hibernate read values from .properties file every time or are does values saved in RAM?

What is most efficient way to update this kind of variable value without requesting it from DB on every call?
Is there a way to have it saved in ram as in example above and just request check when it was changed in DB or specific file? At request for check, new value would override existing one in class.

Example: at each request value form class (1.350) is returned. after admin requests call to change it, DB has new value "1.500" and old one(1.350) gets overriden. Every next call from user would just return 1.500 without checking it in DB or file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) that supports automatic reloading

Basically have your appVersion in a sample property file say `config.properties` in your war file with the below details

```
appVersion=1.35
key=Value
...
...
```

You can then make use of the [Apache Commons Configuration API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/index.html) in order to load, read, update the property file wherever you would require in your code.

In this way you have your properties create/read/update on the fly without requiring server restarts.

As for hibernate, its properties and mapping files are all contained inside a `SessionFactory` instance, which is a singleton. This sessionFactory instance is quite heavy weighted, shared throughout the application and is **immutable**.

Although not advisable as it can lead your application to be error prone and inconsistent, you can destroy `SessionFactory` instance and create another one, but you need to make sure that none of the `Session` instances are referring to it. In short be prepared for damage control work if you do that.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have tried `commons-configuration2` (new one) but it does just read from file, but i can not get it to auto reload values. I have also tried old `v1.10`. it also just reads value for first time after server restart and FileChangedReloadingStrategy does nothing. I have my `config.properties` file in `/resources/` folder. When i change value of atributes by hand it just does not read it.

Comment: @AndroidTank hello there, did you go get a chance to look into this [link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_reloading.html)

Could you post what you have tried?